# The best-looking site in the trilogy?

Tags: discussion, design

So I've just visited the superuser.com beta site and I must say I really like the color schemes and the way everything is so light and bright and just get out of the way for most things.

I feel like, why didn't Stack Overflow use *that* scheme?

Which site, in the SO trilogy, do you like best design-wise?

Comment: Logic would dictate that this question should only have 4 answers, not 6... but then again, when is anything that *should* be dictated by logic *actually* dictated by logic? =)

Comment: Should be CW perhaps? (not that I care, personally)

Comment: And none of those 6 answers were suggesting the serverfault site.

Answer (score 13):

The *best* is Stack Overflow.

- Meta is too sad.
- Super User is too blue.
- Server Fault have good look, but I like orange. :)

---

Color schema at Meta has lot of common with Jeff's opinion on meta discussion, I think. :)
[http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001282.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20100126025309/http://www.codinghorror.com:80/blog/archives/001282.html)

[image]

<sub>(Source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e1d35970b-pi))</sub>

Comment: For some reason, I just imagined the Meta logo crying grey tears ;)

Answer (score 10):

I like the vibrant colors of Super User.

Comment: Agreed. Although it does tend to remind me a lot of the color schemes used by your typical web2.0 apps

Comment: @TheTXI Really web2.0 .... but other sites just feel like Jeff hacked it from the default ASP.NET MVC template ... not really give it a proper scheme

Comment: aigh.  It hurts my eyes to look at it.  I can;t leave that browser window open too long

Answer (score 5):

I really like grayscale and bleak, sad themes, so for me, it's meta.

Comment: +1 - anything else just looks to garish ;)

Comment: Yay, more drab!

Answer (score 2):

And for the 8% of mostly male customers who have some form of colour blindness... they're different?

Answer (score 1):

I think Super User has the nicest general appearance.  Unfortunately, it falls down in a few edge cases and where it fails, it fails spectacularly.

So at the moment I have to vote the original Stack Overflow. But maybe by the end of the week Super User will have it.

Comment: I agree that SU needs a few more days of polish before the playing field is level. And at that point people might changes their opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It's got to be SO.
The easiest on the eye. Clearly differentiated new, answered and accepted questions. I feel like other are missing this with SU's blue being too bright and hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

I like the dashed (should that be dashing?) Server Fault boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I **love** Super User's site and design; that is the best. The colors match well, and the logo is awesome.